# Android AudioRecord Microphone Streaming over UDP to Raspberry Pi

Tags: android, audio, raspberry-pi

I want to create an Android app where the app records live microphone audio from my Android phone and then sends that live audio over UDP to my Raspberry Pi. Then I want the Raspberry Pi to play this audio using a speaker that I have connected to it. I found many ways to stream live audio from an Android app over UDP to a server. How would I make this server on the Raspberry Pi and make it tell the Raspberry Pi to play audio. I mainly need help on the receiving end where the Raspberry Pi receives the audio but it wold also be good if you gave me some tips about how to code the Android app. So basically how will I make the Raspberry Pi play the live microphone audio?

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: any luck so far? Were u able to find any solution?